# tensorflow: default values for input pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was reading Aurelien Geron's book on `Tensorflow`, in particular the chapter on the `Dataset` API and the input pipeline. One thing I noticed was that the input pipeline takes a set of default values for incoming records. The current method seems a bit fragile since it directly depends upon the sequence of columns in the datafiles. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

So here are two examples from the book below. In the first example, the `record_defaults` provides default values to the decode function. Since this is a list, the sequence of the column defaults has to match exactly with the sequence of columns in the CSV file.

```
record_defaults=[0, np.nan, tf.constant(np.nan, dtype=tf.float64), "Hello", tf.constant([])]
parsed_fields = tf.io.decode_csv('1,2,3,4,5', record_defaults)
parsed_fields
```

Or another example would be:

```
def preprocess(line):
    defs = [0.] * n_inputs + [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32)]
    fields = tf.io.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=defs)
    x = tf.stack(fields[:-1])
    y = tf.stack(fields[-1:])
    return (x - X_mean) / X_std, y
```

In the second example, the same dependency is present where the `defs` variable has to layout data in exactly the same sequence as the CSV file.

So this code works just fine, there is no error with it. But it seems a little risky to code the sequence of columns in the defaults based upon the data file. I mean there is no guarantee that future data files will have the columns in the same sequence. In many cases a user might only know the list of column names, but not the sequence.

Hence I was wondering if there is a way to provide a dictionary of default values to the decode function, or some more flexible structure? According to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_csv) this does not seem to be the case.

Hence I was just wondering if anyone had a good solution to reduce this dependency in the code--and prevent future code breakage or fragility?

Comment: Do you want to create a dataset object? Take a look at `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset`, however, it's not completely clear, what exactly you're trying to accomplish. How is it that column order matters?

Comment: Ahh. So I was just doing some simple tests with CSVs. I wanted to create a `tf.dataset` object. The line of code that creates the fragility is `defs = [0.] * n_inputs + [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32)]` is a list of default values. So there is a sequence here that has to match the sequence of fields coming from the `tf.io.decode_csv()`. If the columns in the csv file change, then the code will break. Hence, I was wondering if there is a less fragile way to do this? For example when I parse a tfrecords file, I can provide a `feature_description` for each field by name.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'sequence' part of your question, my bad. Still, I think `experimental.make_csv_dataset` can solve this, since it parses file in order, defined by column names

Comment: Interesting. I checked the document for `experimental.make_csv_dataset` and the problem seems to still be there. Doco says `column_defaults: A optional list of default values for the CSV fields.` I guess I could just not provide column defaults, but then there is no way to guard against corrupt data, etc. Hmm, I have to think about this a bit more.